# Update and delete sqlite database used to populate UI

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite database in an android application that needs to be constantly updated with json data received from internet source. All the rows of the db table that are absent in the received data should be deleted. This fetch and update database operation is done everything a user opens an the activity. The UI of the activity is populated according to the content of the database.

I have 2 options to do this

1. Delete the whole table and insert all the new records in the database everytime.
2. Match the existing database records with the new data and delete records than do not match.

What is the best way to do this so that the UI does not handle and the experience to the end user is good?

Comment: 2nd Option will be good in my opinion

Comment: Consider moving only database changes over the wire instead of redownloading everything every time.

Answer (score 0):

Second method will be good as far as end user UI experience is concerend. As, upgrading DB each time will contain an instance of your application which can cause ANR error.

Answer (score 0):

The second option you've proposed would be a good solution.